# get image from remote server

Tags: android

i have image in sqlserver db.using ksoap2 client webservice for getting image.there i am converting image into base64 encoding and in mobile i am converting it into base64 decoding but i am unable to get image

whats the problem.how i will get image  or any alternative solution for this problem

Thanks in advance

Aswan

Comment: The file is received at the mobile.  When converting from base64 to a picture, the conversions fails.  Is that correct?  Is there any kind of error message. Is it an out of memory error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally i got solution for my problem by creating custom base64 class

Answer (score 1):

If you decode from base64 what you get should be technically an image file and cannot be used directly in the code.

Maybe what you are looking for is something like

```
Image i = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, offset, length);
```

Where "data" is a byte array you have after the decoding, offset should be set to 0 and length equal to data.length.

After that, you can use the image with your views.